# Offset parameter is not working expectedly in - PINE script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]The program plots circles on the highs of candles. But not in every candle. The 'random1' is used as the index for high so that we can draw a circle on a random previous candle. 'random2' is used to avoid drawing in all candles and to randomise this process. Since offset and random1 have same value, we should see the circles exactly on top of each candle. But it seems like 'offsett' is not working as expected.How can I fix this issue?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var int offsett = na
float High = na

random1 = math.random(6,10)
random2 = math.random(4,10)
if random2 > 8
    High := high[int(random1)]

// Calculate offset of the shape[![enter image description here][1]][1]
offsett := int(-random1)

// Plot the circle shape with offset
plotshape(High, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 54), size=size.normal, offset=offsett)
```